# Can't change background-position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-position

I have a body element:

```
<body id="body" class="watermark">
```

Css class "watermark" is:

```
.watermark { background-image: url('/assets/images/watermark.png');
             background-repeat: repeat; 
             background-position: -250px 850px; }
```

I need change background position under some circuumstances:

```
<script>   
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#body").css = ('backgroundPosition','-250px 50px');
   });      
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. I've tryed both `backgroundPosition` and `background-position` but body element is still keeping orginial background-position values defined in css. No error in console. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $("#body").css(backgroundPosition, '-250px 50px');

Comment: Just remove `=` after `css` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('#body').css('background-position', '-250px 50px');
```

or

```
$('#body').css('backgroundPosition', '-250px 50px');
```

Comment: or `$("#body").css('backgroundPosition', '-250px 50px');`

Comment: both properties are valid for position.

Comment: Or  $("#body").css(backgroundPosition, '-250px 50px');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#body').css('background-position', '-250px 50px');
```

Comment: I deleted ";" character but still the same result